# Lua : Function pass memory variable link instead of value

Tags: lua

Lua seems to pass parameters' memory adress to function instead of value
Is that a standard behaviour ?

Following code can be tested at https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

```
local t = {
    Give = {"original"},
    Etapes = {},
}

function check (obj)
for k, v in pairs(obj) do
    if k == "Give" then  
        obj[k] = {"modified"}
    end
end

-- return obj 

end

print ("BEFORE t.Give[1]="..t.Give[1])
check(t)
print ("AFTER  t.Give[1]="..t.Give[1])
```

print result :

```
BEFORE t.Give[1]=original
AFTER t.Give[1]=modified
```

Comment: See the last but one paragraph in https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.1

Comment: Ok didn't saw that paragraph !  Thanks